# JQuery split array elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the ids from some li elements. But I'm not sure how to split the results in the array. So message_1 becomes 1, message_2 becomes 2 and so on.

```
<ul id="chat_viewport">
<li id="message_1">message</li>
<li id="message_2">message this and that</li>
<li id="message_3">3</li>
<li id="message_4">4</li>
<li id="message_5">5</li>
</ul>


<a href="#" class="test">TEST</a>​


$("a.test").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var idarray = $("#chat_viewport")
         .find("li") //Find the li in #chat_viewport
         .map(function() { return this.id; }) //Project Ids
         .get(); //ToArray

var biggest = Math.max.apply( null, idarray );

alert(idarray);
});​
```

I have an example here http://jsfiddle.net/T5x5d/

Comment: try whit this if i've understend : `return this.id.replace('message_', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `.map` function with this:

```
function() { return this.id.replace('message_', ''); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of the format of IDs, then you can use this:

```
.map(function() { return this.id.split('_')[1]; })
```

P.S. Put entire code in question. It is not long and if something happens to your jsFiddle, then other users won't understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

modify it to look like this :

```
$("a.test").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var idarray = $("#chat_viewport")
         .find("li") //Find the li in #chat_viewport
         .map(function() { return this.id.split('_')[1]; }) //Project Ids
         .get(); //ToArray

var biggest = Math.max.apply( null, idarray );

alert(idarray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a to much but:

```
$("a.test").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idarray = $("#chat_viewport")
        .find("li") //Find the li in #chat_viewport
        .map(function() {
            var match = /(\d+)/.exec(this.id);
            return match !== null ? parseInt(match[0]) : 0;
         }) //Project Ids
         .get(); //ToArray
    var biggest = Math.max.apply( null, idarray );

    alert(biggest);
});
```

i dont take to the account that it must have the id of message_ just a number in its id and convert it to a number(if you want to return an array with numbers) if no number was found it will return a 0.